# How can i conditionally required the column based on other column value while import using laravel package maatwebsite excel

Tags: laravel, validation, import, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

Here is my PHP class of Imports, in which i in excel i have a column of Invite Type, as i am using a WithHeadingRow trait so when importing i am accessing via heading and in other two columns i have email and telephone number, what i want to do is when invite_type is "email" then email field should be required, and when invite_type is "sms" then telephone_number field should be required, and when invite_type is "both" then both email and telephone_number fields are required.

```
<?php

  namespace App\Imports;

  use App\Models\InviteUser;
  use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
  use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\RequiredIf;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class ClientsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation, SkipsEmptyRows
{
  
  public function model(array $row)
  {
    dd($row);
  }

  public function rules(): array
  {
    return [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:125'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:125'],
        'email' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'email',
            'distinct',
            [new RequiredIf(empty($this->invite_type) || in_array($this->invite_type,['email','both'])), 'string', 'email','distinct'],
        ],
        'telephone_number' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            [new RequiredIf(empty($this->invite_type) || in_array($this->invite_type,['sms','both'])), 'string','distinct'],
        ],
        'invite_type' => ['required', 'string', 'in:email,sms,both'],
    ];
  }

  public function customValidationMessages()
  {
    return [
        'invite_type.in' => 'The selected invite_type is invalid. Allowed types are following (email, sms, both).',
       'telephone_number.required' => 'The telephone number field is required when invite type is both or sms.',
        'email.required' => 'The email field is required when invite_type is both or email.',
    ];
  }

  public function customValidationAttributes()
  {
    return [
        'invite_type' => 'invite type',
        'telephone_number' => 'Telephone number',
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope this may help you `['required_if:invite_type,email,both', 'string', 'email', 'distinct']
['required_if:invite_type,sms,both', 'string', 'distinct']`

Comment: Hi @PackiyarajPatchath thanks for your response, are you sure we can use column like this with ToModel ?